# Check a mongodb connection with Pentaho

Tags: java, mongodb, pentaho, kettle

I would like to check on my Pentaho (Kettle) transformation if the mongodb database is available.
Currently, I have an error like this when I put a wrong configuration :

```
2013/04/30 17:10:07 - MongoDb Output.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2013/04/30 17:10:07 - MongoDb Output.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't say something
......
```

I want to put all the data in a file instead of the mongodb database if this database isn't available.
I don't know if this is possible with Pentaho...

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: You are trying to output data from Pentaho into MongoDB?

Comment: yes and it works but I want to do like a backup in a file if there is a problem with the database

Answer (score 0):

If you make hop from your **TABLE_OUTPUT** step to a **TEXT_FILE** step, it is automatically marked as error handeling hop. The former data stream stays the same so if you get error while connecting or some else, you cam pass the data to the file specified in the TEXT_FILE step.